# display the recently inserted record into MySQL database in next android activity for editing purpose

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Below is the code that inserts data into MySQL database from an android activity.Now, I want to display that recently inserted data in the edit-text and spinner fields of the next activity. I desperately need a solution, if my problem is unclear to you please ask questions. I am using stackoverflow as my last resort.

```
insertbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            getDatafromForm();
            SendDataToServer(opened,closed,site,tech,own,status,category,affected_kpis,bsc,grid,cells,priority,ana,recom,alarm,receiver,carboncopy);
        }
    });
}

public void getDatafromForm(){
    opened=date_opened.getText().toString();
    closed=date_closed.getText().toString();
    site=sit.getText().toString();
    tech=tech_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    own=owner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    status=status_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    category=category_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    affected_kpis=kpis.getText().toString();
    bsc=rnc.getText().toString();
    grid=grid_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    cells=affected_cells.getText().toString();
    priority=priority_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    ana=analysis.getText().toString();
    recom=recommendations.getText().toString();
    alarm=alarms.getText().toString();
    receiver=to.getText().toString();
    carboncopy=cc.getText().toString();
}

public void SendDataToServer(final String dateopened,final String dateclosed,final String site,final String tech,
                             final String own,
                             final String status,final String category, final String affected_kpis,final String bsc,
                             final String grid,final String cells,final String priority,
                             final String ana,final String recom,final String alarm,final String receiver,
                             final String carboncopy ){
    class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
            String quickdo=dateopened;
            String quickdc=dateclosed;
            String quicksite=site;
            String quicktech=tech;
            String quickowner=own;
            String quickstatus=status;
            String quickcategory=category;
            String quickaffected_kpis=affected_kpis;
            String quickbsc=bsc;
            String quickgrid=grid;
            String quickcells=cells;
            String quickpriority=priority;
            String quickanalysis=ana;
            String quickrecom=recom;
            String quickalarm=alarm;
            String quickreceiver=receiver;
            String quickcarboncopy=carboncopy;

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date_opened",quickdo));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date_closed",quickdc));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("site",quicksite));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("technology",quicktech));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("owner",quickowner));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status",quickstatus));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category",quickcategory));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("affected_kpis",quickaffected_kpis));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bsc_rnc",quickbsc));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grid",quickgrid));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("affected_cells",quickcells));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("priority",quickpriority));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("analysis",quickanalysis));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("recommendations",quickrecom));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alarm",quickalarm));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("receiver",quickreceiver));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("carboncopy",quickcarboncopy));



            HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(insert_url);
            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse httpResponse=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity=httpResponse.getEntity();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           // JSONObject myobject=myparser.getJSONFromUrl(insert_url);
            return "Successfull";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(createRecord.this,"Data successfully submitted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //pass json object result with the intent here
           /* Intent i=new Intent(createRecord.this,EditActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("data",result.toString());
            startActivity(i); */
        }
    }
    SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(dateopened,dateclosed,site,tech,own,status,category,affected_kpis,bsc,grid,cells,priority,
            ana,recom,alarm,receiver,carboncopy );


}
```

My php script is:

```
   <?php
include "connect.php";

//extract($_POST);


$date_opened=$_POST['date_opened'];
$date_closed=$_POST['date_closed'];
$site=$_POST['site'];
$technology=$_POST['technology'];
$owner=$_POST['owner'];
$status=$_POST['status'];
$category=$_POST['category'];
$affected_kpis=$_POST['affected_kpis'];
$bsc_rnc=$_POST['bsc_rnc'];
$grid=$_POST['grid'];
$affected_cells=$_POST['affected_cells'];
$priority=$_POST['priority'];
$analysis=$_POST['analysis'];
$recommendations=$_POST['recommendations'];
$alarms=$_POST['alarm'];
$receiver=$_POST['receiver'];
$carboncopy=$_POST['carboncopy'];
$age;

$rec="SELECT COUNT(grid) as total from data where grid='$grid'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$rec);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$total = $row['total'];


if(strtotime($date_closed)=='0'){
    $age=0;
}
else{
$difference=strtotime($date_closed) - strtotime($date_opened);
$age= floor($difference/(60 * 60* 24));
}



$sql = "INSERT into data set 
        date_opened = '$date_opened',
        date_closed = '$date_closed',
        aging='$age',
        site = '$site',
        technology='$technology',
        owner = '$owner',
        status = '$status',
        category = '$category',
        affected_kpis = '$affected_kpis',
        bsc_rnc = '$bsc_rnc',
        grid = '$grid',
        recurrence='$total',
        affected_cells = '$affected_cells',
        priority = '$priority',
        analysis = '$analysis',
        recommendations = '$recommendations',
        alarm = '$alarms',
        receiver='$receiver',
        carboncopy='$carboncopy'

";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    $json= array('id'=>$last_id,'date_opened'=>$date_opened,'date_closed'=>$date_closed,'aging'=>$age,'site'=>$site,
                'technology'=>$technology,'owner'=>$owner,'status'=>$status,'category'=>$category,
                 'affected_kpis'=>$affected_kpis,'bsc_rnc'=>$bsc_rnc,'grid'=>$grid,'recurrence'=>$total,
                'affected_cells'=>$affected_cells,'priority'=>$priority,'analysis'=>$analysis,
                 'recommendations'=>$recommendations,'alarm'=>$alarms,'receiver'=>$receiver,'carboncopy'=>$carboncopy);

    //echo 'Data Inserted Successfully';
    echo json_encode($json);
}
else {
    echo "Try Again " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom pojo class and set recent insert data to it. after then pass pojo class to next activity.

Like, Create pojo class and set all the value.

> ```
> public class Test implements Serializable {
> String opened, closed;
> ```

```
public Test(String opened, String closed) {
    this.opened = opened;
    this.closed = closed;
}

public String getOpened() {
    return opened;
}

public void setOpened(String opened) {
    this.opened = opened;
}

public String getClosed() {
    return closed;
}

public void setClosed(String closed) {
    this.closed = closed;
}
```

}

```
Test test = new Test(date_opened.getText().toString(), 
date_closed.getText().toString());

Intent intent = new Intent(createRecord.this,EditActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("data",test);
startActivity(intent);
```

You can get data like,

```
 Test test = (Test) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data");
 test.getClosed() // for get closed value
 etc..
```

First, you have to get response from api as a string after then you can convert in JSON object.
You can get response like this.

```
 static String json = "";
 static InputStream is = null;

 DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
 httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

 HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
 HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
 is = httpEntity.getContent();
try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
```

Now, you can convert response to JSON object or you will do via GSON lib also.

Comment: How will I update the previously inserted data in the database?

Comment: You have to keep id for it, after then you can fire update query where that id.

Comment: The id field is auto-incremented in the database how can I fetch it here in my android application... my main problem is I'm having trouble in fetching data from the database in order to show it in the respective fields of next activity.

Comment: Can you post response which you get from SendPostReqAsyncTask?

Comment: Also, check this link https://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/, May be help you.

Comment: The response of SendPostReqAsyncTask is "Data successfully submitted" and creates a new record in database with user inserted values. Check my PHP script I just want to fetch that JSON object in a variable in my android activity from where I am sending the insert request.

Comment: Please try with code which i added for getting response from API. Also, send me log what will you get in "json" string?

Comment: Do you check code? Give me log of data which is stored in "json" string. So, i can give you sample for how to fetch data according to your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class CreateNewData extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, JSONObject> {
    String opened=date_opened.getText().toString();
    String closed=date_closed.getText().toString();
    String site=sit.getText().toString();
    String tech=tech_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String own=owner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String status=status_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String category=category_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String affected_kpis=kpis.getText().toString();
    String bsc=rnc.getText().toString();
    String grid=grid_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String cells=affected_cells.getText().toString();
    String priority=priority_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String ana=analysis.getText().toString();
    String recom=recommendations.getText().toString();
    String alarm=alarms.getText().toString();
    String receiver=to.getText().toString();
    String carboncopy=cc.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {

        List<NameValuePair> param=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date_opened",opened));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date_closed",closed));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("site",site));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("technology",tech));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("owner",own));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status",status));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category",category));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("affected_kpis",affected_kpis));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bsc_rnc",bsc));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grid",grid));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("affected_cells",cells));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("priority",priority));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("analysis",ana));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("recommendations",recom));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alarm",alarm));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("receiver",receiver));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("carboncopy",carboncopy));

        JSONObject json=jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(insert_url,"POST",param);
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());





        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        super.onPostExecute(json);
        try {
            int id=json.getInt("id");

            if(id==0){
                Toast.makeText(createRecord.this,json.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Toast.makeText(createRecord.this,"Data Not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(createRecord.this,json.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i=new Intent(createRecord.this,EditActivity.class);
                //passing data as json object to next activity
                i.putExtra("data",json.toString());
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the PHP code will be like this:

```
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    $json['id']=$last_id;
    $json['date_opened']=$date_opened;
    $json['date_closed']=$date_closed;
    $json['site']=$site;
    $json['technology']=$technology;
    $json['owner']=$owner;
    $json['status']=$status;
    $json['category']=$category;
    $json['affected_kpis']=$affected_kpis;
    $json['bsc_rnc']=$bsc_rnc;
    $json['grid']=$grid;
    $json['affected_cells']=$affected_cells;
    $json['priority']=$priority;
    $json['analysis']=$analysis;
    $json['recommendations']=$recommendatons;
    $json['alarm']=$alarms;
    $json['receiver']=$receiver;
    $json['carboncopy']=$carboncopy;
    $json['message']="Data inserted successfully";
    echo json_encode($json);
    //echo 'Data Inserted Successfully';
    echo json_encode($json);
}

    else {
        $json['id']=0;
        $json['message']="Data not inserted";
        echo json_encode($json);}
    ?>
```